# Are batched requests sent over Neo4j REST API executed in parallel

Tags: rest, neo4j

If I use Neo4j REST Batch endpoint, are the requests in the same batch executed in parallel? I suspect not, because how else would one request be able to refer to another in the same batch? But I haven't been able to find any documentation that clearly states one way or the other, and I am trying to make a recommendation to someone else about the performance of REST batches vs. transactional Cypher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not executed in parallel but sequentially.

But they are streamed, if you use the header: `X-Stream:true`